# How to stop jar from executing inside container, with green border?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, comodo-firewall

Windows 10 (64-bit)

I'm trying to run an executable jar. It opens & runs fine, but there is a green border around the window, and any application which is opened by this app, also has a green border around the window, but other apps don't. For example, the app is a file downloader, and has a button to open the destination directory in Windows Explorer; the child explorer window has a green border, but explorer windows opened via [Windows key] + E, don't. It only does this with this jar. Running other programs normally (ex: chrome, etc.) don't have this green border. The jar is an app I've used many times before, but I haven't used it in a while, so I downloaded it again, and encountered this weird behavior.

I've tried running it from windows explorer via double click, and via right click open with... [JVM]. I have 2 JVM's installed (Oracle [v8] & Zulu [v16]); I've tried running with both of them, and I get the same behavior.

Also, files which are downloaded by the app are only visible in the windows explorer which is opened by the app (i.e. the ones with the green border). But if I open another windows explorer via [windows key] + E, the files & folders aren't there at all. Worst of all, windows will not allow my to copy the files from the green border explorer to the regular explorer.

This behavior seems to me, to scream that the app is executing inside a seamless container, but I didn't know that windows had full support for that. I played around with Docker & Windows subsystem for linux a while back, but as I recall, I never got it working, and this is the first time that I've seen a window showing up with the green border.

I've tried googling, but all I seem to find are things on linux containers or docker running inside WSL. I don't see anything talking about apps running directly from windows explorer.

How can I get this jar to stop executing in this container (or whatever it's doing), and just run normally in windows? Or, at least, how can I get the files out of the container, and onto my main drive?

thank you,
-Yurelle

Comment: Have you searched this behavior online? What is your Java version? What are its settings?

Comment: Yea, I've searched, but all I seem to find are linux containers or docker running inside WSL. I don't see anything talking about apps running directly from windows explorer. I'm running Java 16. Settings are all stock, from the installers.

Comment: That information needs to be in the question. Use the EDIT button please.

Comment: Is that sufficient?

Comment: @Yurelle - No; It sounds like your using a sandbox to launch the Java application. Sandboxie is an open source project that does something similar. Tell us more about your Windows environment.

Comment: ok, it looks like I do have sandboxie-plus v0.53b installed. I don't remember installing that. I guess I installed it back when I was trying to get docker & WSL working. I opened Sandboxie, and then ran the java app, and it's showing up with the green border, but the Sandboxie manager only shows "DefaultBox"; I don't see any processes. I tried right clicking on DefaultBox, and selecting "Terminate All Programs", but the java app didn't die. So, does that mean it's not running in Sandboxie?

Comment: I'm not sure what else I have installed, I experiment with a lot of stuff. Is there anyway to have windows tell me if it's running in some other VM/Container system? The task manager process just shows it as a norma JVM process.

Comment: @Ramhound Nevermind. I figured it out. Apparently my "new"-ish antivirus that I switched to several months ago (Comodo Anti-virus) has a built-in containerization feature, where if it doesn't know what an application is, it will automatically execute it within Comodo's proprietary container system. I did not know it was doing that. Thank you for pointing out the Sandboxie, that got me on the path to figuring it out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Yurelle - You would typically launch the application with Sandboxie, in order ton put it within it's protected sandbox environment, sounds like you have an unused Sandboxie configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Comodo Antivirus/Firewall has a built-in feature where if it doesn't know what an application is, but it's not quite suspicious enough to be fully quarantined, Comodo will divert the program to execute inside Comodo's custom container system. You can disable it, or modify the rules by going to the main Comodo manager app; it's the feature called "Auto-Containment". Click on that, and it will take you to the "Containment" node in the settings tree, where you can disable it or change the rule priorities.

For me anyway, apps running inside Sandboxie containers have a yellow border. But apps running inside the Comodo Antivirus have a bright green border. The color difference helped me realize there was another containerization system at play.

Comment: Sandboxie was sold a good 2 years before it went open source, I forget the company, but I wouldn't be shocked if the IP was purchased by Comodo.  Sandboxie itself was made open source, does not mean, it wasn't put in commercial software. That is likely the reason it seems so familar.

Comment: That makes sense.